# Not able to access OpenVPN out of network group

Tags: vpn, openvpn, authentication, timeout

I have installed Open VPN on Esxi using [this document](https://docs.openvpn.net/getting-started/deploying-the-access-server-appliance-on-vmware-esxi/).

The Open VPN installed on Esxi successfully and has an IP: `10.0.0.21` and running on port 943.

To access it from outside, I logged into my router and did a port-forward.

From: `MY-PUBLIC-IP:943` to `10.0.0.21:943`.

Now, when I navigate to `https://MY-PUBLIC-IP:943`, I am able to see my open VPN page and able to download Windows client.

Also able to connect to VPN when I connect from office as I am able to reach (`10.0.0.21`), open VPN Image.

But If I switch to my phone Wifi and try connecting ,I am still able to reach `MY-PUBLIC-IP:943`, but connection times out while authenticating .

I did similar setup for PiVPN on for my home and it works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the server settings to point to external IP.

To do that login to Open VPN admin page and click Server Netweork Settings and then Update your WAN or External IP address , on hostname or IP Address.

[image]